# How to execute a call instruction with a 64-bit absolute address?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, jit, function-call

I am trying to call a function - that should have an absolute address when compiled and linked - from machine code. I am creating a function pointer to the desired function and trying to pass that to the call instruction, but I noticed that the call instruction takes at most a 16 or 32-bit address. Is there a way to call an absolute 64-bit address?

I am deploying for the x86-64 architecture and using NASM to generate the machine code.

I could work with a 32-bit address if I could be guaranteed that the executable would be for sure mapped to the bottom 4GB of memory, but I am not sure where I could find that information.

**Edit**: I cannot use the callf instruction, as that requires me to disable 64-bit mode.

**Second Edit**: I also do not want to store the address in a register and call the register, as this is performance critical, and I cannot have the overhead and performance hit of an indirect function call.

**Final Edit**: I was able to use the rel32 call instruction by ensuring that my machine code was mapping to the first 2GB of memory. This was achieved through mmap with the MAP_32BIT flag (I'm using linux):

> MAP_32BIT (since Linux 2.4.20, 2.6)
>                 Put  the  mapping into the first 2 Gigabytes of the
>                 process address space.  This flag is supported only
>                 on  x86-64,  for  64-bit programs.  It was added to
>                 allow thread stacks to be  allocated  somewhere  in
>                 the  first 2GB of memory, so as to improve context-
>                 switch performance on some early 64-bit processors.
>                 Modern  x86-64  processors no longer have this per‐
>                 formance problem,  so  use  of  this  flag  is  not
>                 required  on  those systems.  The MAP_32BIT flag is
>                 ignored when MAP_FIXED is set.

Comment: Put it in a 64 bit register and call that? Should be easy to verify.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: He is probably calling his assembler from C++, using a C++ function pointer, but that is indeed irrelevant to this question about x86-64 assembler.

Comment: @Brian I took out the C++ tag

Comment: @RudyVelthuis See my second edit to the question

Comment: What kind of performance hits do you expect, compared to the alternatives, if any?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552158/call-an-absolute-pointer-in-x86-machine-code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

related: [Handling calls to (potentially) far away ahead-of-time compiled functions from JITed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947302/handling-calls-to-potentially-far-away-ahead-of-time-compiled-functions-from-j) has more about JITing, especially allocating your JIT buffer near the code it wants to call, so you can use efficient `call rel32`.  Or what to do if not.

Also [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552158/call-an-absolute-pointer-in-x86-machine-code) is a good canonical Q&A about `call` or `jmp` to an absolute address.

---

TL:DR: To call a function by name, just use `call func` like a normal person and let the assembler + linker take care of it.  Since you say you're using NASM, I guess you're actually generating the machine code with an assembler.  It sounded like a more complicated question, but I think you were just trying to ask if the normal way was safe.

---

[Indirect `call r/m64` (`FF /2`)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) takes a 64-bit register or memory operand in 64-bit mode.

So you can do

```
func equ  0x123456789ab
; or if func is a regular label

mov   rax, func          ; mov r64, imm64,  or mov r32, imm32 if it fits
call  rax
```

Normally you'd put a label address into a register with `lea rax, [rel func]`, but if that's encodeable then you'd just use `call rel32`.

---

Or, **if you know what address your machine code will be stored in**, you can use the normal direct `call rel32` encoding, after you calculate the difference in address from the target to the end of the `call` instruction.

If you don't want to use an indirect call, then the `rel32` encoding is your only option.  Make sure your machine code goes into the low 2GiB so it can reach any address in the low 4GiB.

---

> if I could be guaranteed that the executable would be for sure mapped to the bottom 4GB of memory

Yes, this is the default code model for Linux, Windows, and OS X.  AMD64 call / jump instructions, and RIP-relative addressing, only use `rel32` encodings, so all systems default to the "small" code model where code and static data are in the low 2GiB, so it's guaranteed that the linker can just fill in a rel32 to reach up to 2G forward or 2G backward.

The [x86-64 System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html) does discuss Large / Huge code models, but IDK if anyone ever uses that, because of the inefficiency of addressing data and making calls.

---

re: efficiency: yes, `mov` / `call rax` is less efficient.  I think it's significantly slower if branch prediction misses and can't provide a target prediction from the BTB.  However, even `call rel32` and `jmp rel32` still need the BTB for full performance.  See [Slow jmp-instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811901/slow-jmp-instruction) for experimental results from relative `jmp next_insn` slowing down when there are too many in a giant loop.

With hot branch predictors, the indirect version is only extra code size and an extra uop (the `mov`).  It might consume more prediction resources, but maybe not even that.

See also [What branch misprediction does the Branch Target Buffer detect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280817/what-branch-misprediction-does-the-branch-target-buffer-detect)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info on the default code model. Do you happen to have a source I could look at?

Comment: @AlexanderBolinsky: yes, that URL in the last paragraph of my answer is a link to the official ABI standard.  See also the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to other ABIs.

Comment: @PeterCordes: What is the difference in performance between `call rel32` and `call r64`?

Comment: I get what they do. What is the difference in **performance** between those two?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Added some stuff about performance of direct jumps, which do still need prediction resources.   Oops, I see I missed a word when reading your previous comment.  Too many mental context switches between this and another answer thread.

Comment: Actually, two words. <g>

Answer (score 2):

In the new [APX](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html) [extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Performance_Extensions) Intel added a new `JMPABS` instruction that receives a 64-bit immediate as absolute jump target

Unfortunately there's no `CALLABS`, so you'll need to work around it like this

```
nearby_trampoline:
    jmpabs target64
...
call nearby_trampoline
```

I don't know if it's faster than the traditional `mov reg, target64; call reg` sequence or not. However APX also added 16 more registers and also 3-operand integer instructions (i.e. non-destructive destinations) so register and I/O pressure likely won't exist anymore and you can just spare one register for the absolute address and use `call reg` directly

Comment: I'd expect `mov reg,imm64` / `call reg` is still faster than jmp/call. (I added an APX footnote to my answer on [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36511513) the other day).  Good point that existing code being adapted to APX can use one of the new registers for the jump target even if all 16 old regs are occupied, at the cost of three extra bytes of code-size (REX2 instead of REX for `mov r16, imm64`, and a REX2 on the `call r16`, vs. `mov rax, imm16` / `call rax`)

Comment: (Also, I'd recommend against using the word "far" in you example label names.  It's a long distance, but it's not a `far` jump to a new `cs`.  Perhaps `nearby_abs_jmp`, or `nearby_trampoline`, since the point is that the `call` target is within rel32 range, probably very close to the call site).  Hrm, if we're putting other stuff near the call site, maybe just put the absolute address as data and `call qword [RIP+rel32]`, like how `gcc -fno-plt` does code-gen.  But then you're dependent on d-cache hits to not stall.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't think your mention of `mov rax, imm16` is correct

Comment: @ecm: Oops, I meant `rax, imm64` / `call rax`. of course.  I typoed 16 since I guess I was still thinking about the register number I picked.